# How do I join 2 columns together from 2 different views?

Tags: sql, oracle

Using oracle SQL developer,

I have two views that have different columns. How can I join column 1 from view A into view B? I want to join `AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME CLI_NAME` from view B into view A.

### View A

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "KPRD"."AC_INPUT_AUDIT" ("CLIENT", "SEQUENCE_CODE", "EMPLOYEE", "ORIGINAL_DATE", "HOURS_SPENT", "LONG_DESCRIPTION", "TIME_AT_ACTUAL", "MANAGER")
AS
  SELECT CLIENT,
    SEQUENCE_CODE,
    EMPLOYEE,
    ORIGINAL_DATE,
    HOURS_SPENT,
    LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    TIME_AT_ACTUAL,
    MANAGER
  FROM TIME_DETAILS
  WHERE MANAGER BETWEEN 'AAGG' AND 'AZJE'
  AND ORIGINAL_DATE    > '28/SEP/2012'
  AND TIME_AT_ACTUAL ! = 0;
```

### View B

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "KPRD"."AC_AR_INV_BAL" ("CLIENT", "CLI_NAME", "PARTNER", "PAR_NAME", "MANAGER", "REFERENCE", "STATUS_CODE", "INVOICE_DATE", "TIME_BILLED", "GROUP_CLIENT_CODE", "GRPCLI_NAME", "INVOICE_BALANCE")
AS
  SELECT AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLIENT CLIENT,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME CLI_NAME,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PARTNER PARTNER,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PAR_NAME PAR_NAME,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER MANAGER,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE REFERENCE,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.STATUS_CODE STATUS_CODE,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_DATE INVOICE_DATE,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.TIME_BILLED TIME_BILLED,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GROUP_CLIENT_CODE GROUP_CLIENT_CODE,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GRPCLI_NAME GRPCLI_NAME,
    AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE
  FROM AR_INVOICE_INQ_V
  WHERE MANAGER BETWEEN 'AAGG' AND 'AZGG';
```

Comment: 1) `How can I join column 1 from view A into view B?` 2) `I want to join AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME CLI_NAME from view B into view A.` A little bit confusing, isn't it? Are `AR_INVOICE_INQ_V` and `TIME_DETAILS` tables related to each other (primary/foreign key relationship)? Or you just want all data from `View1` + one column from `View2` despite the fact that those data from View2 might have a little sense when looking at a record as a logical unit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to join `column 1` from `view A` into `view B`, both tables or views have to have the `column 1`. If you want to join `AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME CLI_NAME` from `view B` into `view A`, `View A` has to have the column `CLI_NAME`. Otherwise you cannot do a join based on `CLI_NAME` column.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for joining views is the same as for tables. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I *think* you want all the columns from view `A` and one additional column from view `B`. Assuming `CLIENT` has a common value on both the syntax would be something like:

```
SELECT AIA.CLIENT,
    AIA.SEQUENCE_CODE,
    AIA.EMPLOYEE,
    AIA.ORIGINAL_DATE,
    AIA.HOURS_SPENT,
    AIA.LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    AIA.TIME_AT_ACTUAL,
    AIA.MANAGER,
    AAIB.CLI_NAME
FROM AC_INPUT_AUDIT AIA
JOIN AC_AR_INV_BAL AAIB ON AAIB.CLIENT = AIA.CLIENT;
```

This seems to assume there will be a one-to-one relationship between the records in both views, which seems unlikely, particularly since the `MANAGER` filters are different. So you might get a different set of results back to what you expect, possibly with duplicates and/or missing records. An outer join might address that but might also make it worse, so you'll need to be clearer how the views are related and what you're trying to achieve.

If you have access to the underlying tables, you might find it more performant to join those, but you'd probably need to test it both ways.